# Powershell - Write To Log File Order By Newest

Tags: powershell, logging

I'm writing to a **.csv** log file using this function :

```
function Write-Log {
     [CmdletBinding()]
     param(
         [Parameter()]
         [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
         [string]$Message,

         [Parameter()]
         [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
         [ValidateSet('Information','Warning','Error')]
         [string]$Severity = 'Information'
     )

     [pscustomobject]@{
         Time = (Get-Date -f g)
         Message = $Message
         Severity = $Severity
     } | Export-Csv -Path $LogFilePath -Append -NoTypeInformation
 }
```

Everything works fine besides the fact that it assigns each record from top to bottom. 
From the oldest to the newest. 
This means that each time I have to scroll down to the bottom of the **.csv** in order to see the the last run of the script. 
How can I change the function so it will present the latest record at the top and the oldest at the bottom?

Comment: Attempting to insert a line at the top of the file every time you write to it will become pretty slow. Have you considered just reading the last log line? `Import-Csv $LogFilePath |Select -Last 1`. Or changing the `Time` format to something sortable (like `Get-Date -f o`), and then just sorting the entries? `Import-Csv $LogFilePath |Sort-Object Time -Descending`

Comment: As I understand from you - It's an expensive process since I'll have to recreate the file each time I'll insert a record in it? 
I understand that there are power shell commands that can assist me with that. The problem that it suppose to be a client friendly solution. Therefor I can't use powershell commands.

Comment: Does _client friendly_ and the fact that you create a log file in the form of a CSV file mean that people open it in Excel? Excel can sort from Z-A really quick..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to slow your process you can rewrite file each time by replace export-csv to set-content:

```
Set-Content -Value ($_+(Get-Content $LogFilePath )) -Path $LogFilePath
```

Nut you make sure that filepath is exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the logging will become slow, but do want it all to be in CSV format, this should do what you want:

```
function Write-Log {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Message,

        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidateSet('Information','Warning','Error')]
        [string]$Severity = 'Information'
    )
    # get the content of the file so far (if any) and skip the headers
    $oldData = Get-Content -Path $LogFilePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Skip 1
    # overwrite the file with this entry
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Time = (Get-Date -f g)
        Message = $Message
        Severity = $Severity
    } | Export-Csv -Path $LogFilePath -NoTypeInformation
    # append the older data to it
    if ($oldData) { $oldData | Add-Content -Path $LogFilePath }
}

$LogFilePath = 'D:\test.csv'
Write-Log -Message 'First message: all is well'
Write-Log -Message 'Second message: attention please' -Severity Warning
Write-Log -Message "Third message: something bad happened" -Severity Error
```

Result:

> ```
> "Time","Message","Severity"
> "5-3-2020 16:24","Third message: something bad happened","Error"
> "5-3-2020 16:24","Second message: attention please","Warning"
> "5-3-2020 16:24","First message: all is well","Information"
> ```

<sup>I'm on a Dutch system, so the timestamp may look different in your case</sup>